# werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'result'. Did you forget to specify values ['search']?

Tags: url, flask

I want to create a search function, I'll add it later, now I'm just concerned about my URLs. When I search, I want to have the thing that I searched for in the URL. But every time I get this error:
werkzeug.routing.BuildError: Could not build url for endpoint 'result'. Did you forget to specify values ['search']?

this is my python file

```
@app.route("/search")
def search():
    search = request.form.get("search")
    return redirect(url_for('result', search=search))

@app.route("/result/<search>")
def result(search):
    return render_template("result.html")
```

And here is my HTML with the form

```
     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="{{ url_for('search')}}">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" name="search" placeholder="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is beacause `search` is `None`

You should implement your search in this way:

HTML

```
<form method='GET' action='/search'>
<input type='text' name='search'>
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

Python

```
@app.route('/search')
def search():
    if 'search'  not in request.args:
       #return normal page
    #Do stuff
    return redirect(url_for('result',search=request.args['search']))

@app.route('/result/<search>')
def result(search):
   #Show the result
   return search
```